# Which PHP modules are required by the SDK

Tags: php, google-app-engine, archlinux

On Arch Linux PHP appears to be compiled with a lot of `--enable-XYZ=shared`, like `--enable-bcmath=shared`. But that means that functionality is has to be explicitly enabled in `php.ini` (or an additional ini file).

Looking at the `google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/check_environment.php` file I can see the *bcmath* is required but I also have the following modules in `/usr/lib/php/modules` (and which are **enabled** by default):

- bcmath.so
- bz2.so
- calendar.so
- curl.so **enabled**
- dba.so
- exif.so
- ftp.so
- gettext.so **enabled**
- gmp.so
- iconv.so
- imap.so
- mysql.so
- mysqli.so
- openssl.so
- pdo_mysql.so
- phar.so
- posix.so
- shmop.so
- soap.so
- sockets.so
- sysvmsg.so
- sysvsem.so
- sysvshm.so
- xmlrpc.so
- zip.so

I'm guessing the mysql extensions should be enabled, but I don't if that means all three of them, or what.

Is there an explanation anywhere of which PHP modules are required by the App Engine SDK or which `--enable-XYX` compiler directives are required?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the things we're concentrating on over the next few releases is providing dev environment that matches what you have in production.

For now, you can get the list of loaded extensions that are available in production from [php-minishell.appspot.com](http://php-minishell.appspot.com), and then use that list to tune your dev setup to match.

```
    >>> print implode(", ", get_loaded_extensions());
    Core, date, ereg, libxml, openssl, pcre, zlib, apc, bcmath, calendar, ctype, 
dom, filter, gd, hash, iconv, json, mbstring, mcrypt, SPL, session, standard, 
OAuth, mysqlnd, PDO, pdo_mysql, Reflection, mysqli, shmop, SimpleXML, soap, 
mysql, tokenizer, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter, GAE Runtime Module, urlfetch_stream_wrapper_plugin, memcache, memcached, 
google_cloud_sql_mysqlnd_plugin
```